# Unicode are of different type? what happens there?

Tags: unicode

How many types of Unicode is available ?
My scenario is when i submit `मनोज` it display `मनोज` but when i submit `ÖîJèTÅÔe` it display as `&#214;&#238;J&#232;T&#197;&#212;` in my computer. Is `मनोज` is different type then `ÖîJèTÅÔe` in Unicode approach?

[image]

Comment: What your computer actually displays is dependent on things like the software you have, which fonts are installed, etc.

Comment: "when i submit" - submit where exactly? It makes a difference, since the receiver expects data in a particular format, so if you don't provide that format then weird things like this can happen.

Comment: i submit text from webform to server which store text in sql server and Datatype of text field is nvarchar

Answer (score 2):

There is only one Unicode. Unicode doesn't have code pages like ANSI.

But Unicode can be written in a couple of ways, like UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32. And there's a difference between UTF-16 Little Endian and UTF-16 Big Endian as well.

Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). It's a great explanation of the differences between them, and much more.